# How to record N-body simulation as a video?

Tags: python, pygame, simulation

I have implemented an N-body simulation using the Barnes-Hut optimisation in Python which runs at a not-unacceptable speed for N=10,000 bodies, but it's still too slow to watch real time.

A new frame is generated each time-step, and to display the frame we must first calculate the new positions of the bodies, and then draw them all. For N=10,000, it takes about 5 seconds to generate one frame (this is waaay too high as Barnes-Hut should be giving better results). The display is done through the pygame module.

I would thus like to record my simulation and replay it once after it's done at a higher speed.

**How can I accomplish this without slowing down the program or exceeding memory limitations?**

One potential solution is simply to save the pygame screen each timestep, but this is apparently very slow.

I thought also about storing the list of positions of the bodies generated each time step, and then redrawing all the frames once the situation finishes. Drawing a frame still takes some time, but not as much time as it takes to calculate the new positions.

Comment: Not really related, but why do you think that "(this is waaay too high as Barnes-Hut should be giving better results)"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Well after comparing runtime with the naive direct O(N^2) algorithm, I verified that Barnes-Hut is indeed working in O(NlogN) as expected. N=10,000 is not even feasible with the direct comparison. However, I have seen other Barnes-Hut implementations online which take only 0.5 s per frame for N=10,000. I have not yet identified the source of the slowness, but I am sure that my code can be made 10 times faster than it is now.

Comment: Are those implementations in *pure python*? Or some other language, or perhaps they use a numerical computing package like `numpy`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : no I don't believe they are generally in python. One of the sims I saw was written in C++. I was wondering if python or pygame are slow. And also I am using numpy. Let me also clarify that the fast sims I saw were ran real time on a standard PC, meaning no parralelisation or special GPU's.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expect a Python implementation to be anywhere near as fast as a C or C++ implementation, especially for this sort of problem. Indeed, I am actually quite impressed that Python is performing only 10x slower than a C++ implementation.

Comment: @juan.arrivillaga 10-100x slower is the right order of magnitude from experience. I'd say 10x means the asker's code is a fairly good python implementation, so I don't think there's much left that can be optimized.

Comment: Given that it looks like running the algorithm itself is the slow part, and since you already have the algorithm written in python, you might want to consider using [cython](http://cython.org/) to speed up just the computation. This way, you could get c-like performance with less effort than a total c rewrite. Note that you would likely have to add some type information to your variables to get a performance boost this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing pure python to various programs which call into compiled code somewhere. Pure python is orders of magnitude slower than code produced by optimizing compilers. Putting the language wars aside, there are cases python performs incredibly fast for a scripting language, and there are cases where it performs slowly.

Many of the demanding python projects I've made have required the use of `numpy/pandas/scipy`, or interpreters such as Pypy in order to compile some python code for a pretty immediate improvement to their execution speed. Compilers tend to produce faster code because they can do optimizations offline rather than trying to perform them with the time pressure of runtime.

---

A video file is the most versatile and easy to manage format for playback, but does require a bit of glue code. To make one, you need a library to encode your visualization frames into video frames. It seems you are already able to generate images per frame, so the only step remaining is to find a video codec.

FFMPEG can be called through its commandline interface to dump your frames into a video file: http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/

The example code for writing is:

```
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
        '-y', # (optional) overwrite output file if it exists
        '-f', 'rawvideo',
        '-vcodec','rawvideo',
        '-s', '420x360', # size of one frame
        '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
        '-r', '24', # frames per second
        '-i', '-', # The imput comes from a pipe
        '-an', # Tells FFMPEG not to expect any audio
        '-vcodec', 'mpeg'",
        'my_output_videofile.mp4' ]

pipe = sp.Popen( command, stdin=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
```

Using this, you can dump a frame using this, if you use numpy arrays:

```
pipe.proc.stdin.write( image_array.tostring() )
```

This approach has been wrapped by the [ffmpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffmpy/0.0.4) library.

---

There is also a simple option, but it sacrifices the versatility of a video file (and the really impressive lossy compression algos). Dump your visualization frames into a file as they are produced. Modify your visualizer to read frames from a file and play them at a specified rate.

It is a straightforward method that I've used in the past to save replay data to watch later when I played [vindinium](http://www.vindinium.org), a multiplayer game for bots.

---

A special mention should be made for memoization, which is extremely well-suited to mathematical computations. Just caching the results of a function defined recursively, you save lots of unnecessary computation at a slight memory cost. Barnes-Hut seems to have a recursive aspect, so you should examine the possibility of memoizing that part.